# Remove from select using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, select

```
var currentSelect = 'option1';
$('#selectMail option[value=' + currentSelect + ']').remove();
```

What I am trying to do above is to remove a option from a select where the option value equals currentSelect. This however returns the error

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #selectMail
>   option[value=dasd@dasd.se]

What is happening here?

Comment: Do you mean to remove the current selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('#selectMail option[value="' + currentSelect + '"]').remove();
```

Comment: what`s the difference if he got quotes [ " ]? i am asking cause i don`t understand  the difference can you explain or post a link please ?

Answer (score 1):

Value of attribute should be wrapped in quotes.

It should be

```
$('#selectMail option[value="' + currentSelect + '"]').remove();
```